# creating a date range from 2 dates with linq.js and momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, linq.js

I want to get all dates between a startDate and an endDate.

I wrap the startDate/endDate with moment() again to clone the start/endDate because they must not be changed.

But still the getDateRange gives me odd results about dates:

```
 testCase.startDate = moment(new Date(2014, 0, 1));
 testCase.endDate = moment(new Date(2014, 0, 27));
```

Although both dates are in 2014 I get a dateRange from december 2013 days?

Why is that?

```
 function getDateRange(startDate, endDate) {
    return Enumerable.range(0, moment(endDate).diff(moment(startDate), 'days') + 1)
      .select(function (offset) {
        return moment(startDate).add(offset, 'days')
      })
      .toArray();
  }
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks like it should work.  Maybe you're interpreting the dates incorrectly.  Remember, only the month starts at `0`.  Maybe you offset the year too when you looked at the values.

Here's an alternate way you can write the query:

```
function getDateRange(startDate, endDate) {
    return Enumerable.Unfold(startDate, "moment($).add(1, 'd')")
        .TakeWhile(function (d) { return d <= endDate; })
        .ToArray();
}
```

---

Based on what I'm seeing in the comments, it appears you're using methods which mutates the dates.  You'll either want to avoid using these methods or clone the date first and manipulate the clones.

```
// without cloning
var date1 = moment.utc([2014, 0, 1]);
console.log(String(date1)); // Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000
var startOfDate1 = date1.startOf('week'); // mutated
console.log(String(date1)); // Sun Dec 29 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000

// using moment()
var date2 = moment.utc([2014, 0, 1]);
console.log(String(date2)); // Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000
var startOfDate2 = moment(date2).startOf('week'); // not mutated
console.log(String(date2)); // Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000

// using clone()
var date3 = moment.utc([2014, 0, 1]);
console.log(String(date3)); // Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000
var startOfDate3 = date3.clone().startOf('week'); // not mutated
console.log(String(date3)); // Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000
```

Comment: I added a screenshot so you can judge yourself!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why it would cause that to happen, and especially by that big an offset.  Maybe try using all utc dates?  See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/9xa9nnkn/) I've been using to test. I'm currently in the Pacific timezone (UTC-7) but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: I updated your fiddle with my linq method. Same result as yours all fine :/ I saw that you use an old linq version, why this?

Comment: That should be the latest stable version (2.2) and I have all my tests still use that.  3 is still in beta so I haven't made the transition yet. But it shouldn't make much of a difference, just the case of the method names need to be changed for our purposes.

Comment: your getDateRange function delivers the same wrong result as mine :-/

Comment: after updating my angular-/moment libraries to a newer version, the dates are correct now!

Comment: That's good.  What version were you using and what version are you using now?

Comment: but as soon this code runs =>   var weeks = Enumerable.from(dateRange)
        .groupBy(function (date) {
          var now = date.startOf('week').isoWeekday(firstDayOfWeek);
          return now.week();
        })  then the dateRange has bad december dates again :/

Comment: Oh... you're using `startOf()` on the date.  That mutates the date.  This is probably why you're seeing all these differences.  You need to make a copy of the date and manipulate the copy.

Comment: Hm... somehow I do not like to clone every moment date nth times in a function. Its confusing. Its not enough to clone the start/endDate , NO I even have to clone every date linq is operating on....

Comment: HAHA... see that Jeff => https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1754,   startOf will be immutable in version 3.0 of momentjs :P